# How to call ajax in my HTML form

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, xml

i have this ajax function:

```
$.ajax({
url: "http://localhost:56472/WebSite2/Service.asmx/Area",
method:"post",
data: {
    l: "custom value",
    b: "custom value",
}
success: function (data) {
    console.log(data.length);
    var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(data);
    var jXml = $(xmlDoc);
    var value = jXml.find("int").text();
    $("#result").text(value);
},
failure: function (err) {
    console.log("could not call the service : " + err);
}
});
```

and i want to use it in this html to display the result:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>WebService Call using HTTP POST</title>
<body>
<form action="http://localhost:56472/WebSite2/Service.asmx/Area" method="POST">
<input name="l">
<input name="b">
<input type="submit" value="Click for Area">
</form>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

can someone tell me how to call this ajax with this form ? and how the complete html will look like ?

Thank you som much :)!

EDIT:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>WebService Call using HTTP POST</title>
<body>
<script>
     $(function () {
            function clickme() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://localhost:56472/WebSite2/Service.asmx/Area",
                    method: "post",
                    data: {
                        l: "custom value",
                        b: "custom value",
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data.length);
                        var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(data);
                        var jXml = $(xmlDoc);
                        var value = jXml.find("int").text();
                        $("#result").text(value);
                    },
                    failure: function (err) {
                        console.log("could not call the service : " + err);
                    }
                });
            };

            $("button").on("click", clickme)
        });
</script>
<form method="POST">
<input name="l">
<input name="b">
<button type="button" onclick="clickme()">Click for Area</button>
</form>
<h1 id="result"></h1>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: Remove action from your form, create a button and bind click event to call your ajax code.  There are a lot of sample on to this.

Comment: @Jules ok can you check my edited code please? what should i write in the onclick method? the ajax doesnt have a name or something so i can call it ?

Comment: $(function(){function clickme(){your ajax code here}; $('button').on('click', clickme });  Suggestion, read jquery documentation to understand the code.

Comment: @Jules can you check the edited code please? i did as you said but nothing is happening, i dont know if am doing something wrong?

Comment: Your code was not formatted properly (partially my fault).  I put the corrected copy here https://jsfiddle.net/u7f1npxq/

Comment: @Jules i edited, but still nothing is happening :( is there is a mistake in my html or my ajax method? im sorry i bothered you but im new to ajax and i really need this to be done. THANK YOU SO MUCH for helping!!

Answer (score 0):

Main steps involved are;

1) include jquery library into your document.

2) bind an event handler to the submit event.

3) get input values for your two input fields.

4) Request the page, send some additional data along and return the result.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    // document ready event. Waits for the document to be fully loaded and ready before working with it.
    $(function () {

        // bind an event handler to the submit event
        $("#myForm").submit(function (event) {

            event.preventDefault(); // cancels the event, meaning that the default action that belongs to the event will not occur.

            // get our forms input values
            var lValue = $('input[name="l"]').val();
            var bValue = $('input[name="b"]').val();

            $.post("http://localhost:56472/WebSite2/Service.asmx/Area", {l: lValue, b: bValue}, function (data) {
                console.log(data.length);
                var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(data);
                var jXml = $(xmlDoc);
                var value = jXml.find("int").text();
                $("#result").text(value);
            }).fail(function (err) {
                console.log("could not call the service : " + err);
            });

        });

    });
</script>
<form id="myForm">
    <input name="l">
    <input name="b">
    <button type="button">Click for Area</button>
</form>
```

Comment: i have a question, the extension of this file would be .html? and can i run it locally on my browser without localhost? because when i tried to run it nothing is happening at all :(

Comment: 1) Yes you can wrap what I posted above into the body of your document. I've only posted the areas of concern. I as a rule usually place all my javascript before the closing body tag. libraries and plugins first (eg, jquery) and then my functions after. 2) No it would need to be run on your localhost or web server to work.

Comment: ok then does it have to be the same server as the webservice? should i write this html inside visual studio?

Comment: @Lamawy take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16556099/ajax-jquery-passing-multiple-parameters-web-services. You should try google "jquery ajax webservices parameters asmx"

Answer (score 0):

You had some basic syntax errors there, but try this (make your appropriate changes):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>WebService Call using HTTP POST</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
function clickme(){
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:56472/WebSite2/Service.asmx/Area",
    method:"post",
    data: {
        l: "custom value",
        b: "custom value",
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data.length);
        var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(data);
        var jXml = $(xmlDoc);
        var value = jXml.find("int").text();
        $("#result").text(value);
    },
    failure: function (err) {
        console.log("could not call the service : " + err);
    }
});
}
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

$("button").on("click", function(){
    clickme();
});
});
</script>
<form method="POST">
<input name="l">
<input name="b">
<button type="button" onclick="clickme()">Click for Area</button>
</form>
<h1 id="result"></h1>
</body>
</html>
```